# Округление числа в js

Tags: javascript, округление

Есть переменная, которая принимает числа вида `1233.0125499813075` - можно ли как то сделать, что бы числа округлялись до вида `1233.01` (2 знака после точки)?

**Обновление**

Прошу прощения, глаза открыл, увидел `.toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 1):

Так можно:

```
var perem = MATH.round(perem * 100) / 100;
```

Comment: @exeption, вот как мне нужно было:
polnsumm = (summa - allsum).toFixed(2);